# Make a Read More toggle in the_content on single-product in Woocoomerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, excerpt

I'm trying to figure out how to make a Read More toggle on the "short-description" in single-product. I can make a ordinary excerpt - but I need to show just the 700 fist characters, followed by a Read More link, that will unfold/toggle the rest of the short desc.so

I don't think the built in excerpt in Wordpress is useful, as we are on single-product? :)

I've been looking for plugins, couldn't find anything useful. Thinking of a function, though I don't have the proper knowledge to create such myself - any ideas for plugins or custom functions?

Comment: No the default excerpt / read more link is not usefull for you. The read more link as default is just a permalink to the full post. You will need to build this by yourself. For example you could create a link/button appended to the short description, this button will than toggle some JS and/or CSS. But that is not in the scope of WP, its normal JS and CSS code. I dont know any plugins which will do exactly what you want sorry.

Comment: Thank. Just needed to make sure - thanks for your comment :)